# Import class and side effects from ES6 module in one statement

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

I have a module which defines a class and defines a custom element using that class

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {}
window.customElements.define('my-ele', MyElement);
```

I can import the class using `import { MyElement } from './myel.js';` but that doesn't register the custom element.
I know I can import side effects using `import './myel.js';` but then I don't have the class

Is there a way of importing the class and also importing the side effects in one statement? I don't like the repetition of this...

```
import './myel.js';
import { MyElement } from './myel.js';
```

Comment: Your module is missing an `export` declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you export IIFE with the side-effect behavior you want as default export and import that as well, it would work.

Something like:

```
export class MyElement extends HTMLElement {}
export default (() => {
    window.customElements.define('my-ele', MyElement); // the code we want to run
})()
```

and import as following:

```
import _, { MyElement } from './myel.js'; // the import here would run the IIFE
```